# React.Js and Polymer CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, polymer

I have a react app I am trying to inject into a Polymer app. The Polymer app will handle the routing, etc, I just need the react app to appear on one of the pages fully styled/functional with event handlers etc. I cannot get the styles to apply properly.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="storm-styles.html">

<script src="../node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../build/react-diagrams/static/js/main.aaa88ec6.js"></script>

<dom-module id="my-view4">
   <template>
     <style include="storm-styles"></style>
   </template>
   <script>
   class MyView4 extends Polymer.Element {
         static get is() { return 'my-view4'; }

         ready() {
           super.ready();
/*
           ReactDOM.render(
             React.createElement(
               Provider,
               null,
               React.createElement(
                 App,
                 null
               )
             ),
             this.shadowRoot
           );*/
         }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView4.is, MyView4);
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

if I uncomment the `ReactDOM.render()` function then the `<style>` element vanishes and the React app doesn't work, but it appears in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that ReactDOM.render() updates the DOM by erasing all nodes and re-writing them. So since I'm writing to this.shadowRoot, the styles get over-written.

This can be solved by adding a container div as follows:

```
<dom-module id="my-view4">
   <template>
     <style include="storm-styles"></style>
     <div id="reactcontainer"></div>
   </template>
   <script>
   class MyView4 extends Polymer.Element {
         static get is() { return 'my-view4'; }

         ready() {
           super.ready();

           ReactDOM.render(
             React.createElement(
               Provider,
               null,
               React.createElement(
                 App,
                 null
               )
             ),
             this.$.reactcontainer
           );
         }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView4.is, MyView4);
   </script>
</dom-module>
```